# Airflow trigger DAG anytime after a google sheet is being updated

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is there any way I can schedule a DAG to be triggered right after a google sheet is being updated?

Not sure if I get any answer from this doc : https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/providers/google/suite/hooks/sheets/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTTPOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/http.html) along with Google drive API https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get

You can also write your own implementation see WebHDFSHook and WebHDFSSensor for reference

Comment: Same as i was thingking, I was thinking in terms of sensor approach.

Comment: on the contrib there's no such sensor yet, also no method in the written hook. in this cases better to write a custom sensor on your own. better way will be to extend HTTPOperator with the approach you stated below.
Good reference for implementation will be also WebHDFSHook and WebHDFSSensor both using WebHDFS REST API

Comment: isnt it this one https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/providers/http/sensors/http/index.html?

Comment: but that will poke still a succes response  is replied right?
Executes a HTTP GET statement and returns False on failure caused by 404 Not Found or response_check returning False.

HTTP Error codes other than 404 (like 403) or Connection Refused Error would fail the sensor itself directly (no more poking).

Comment: Yes you are right, but these will be edge cases, OP wanted to check if existing files is modified.

Answer (score 2):

@Alejandro's direction is right but just expanding on to his answer. You can use HttpSensor operator to do a get request to sheet file by [google drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

```
HttpSensor(
    task_id='http_sensor_check',
    http_conn_id='http_default',
    endpoint='https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId',
    request_params={},
    response_check=,
    poke_interval=5,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Now as per return response [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource), it should return modeifiedtime, which you can see in the response in `response_check`

```
response_check=lambda response: response.json()['modifiedTime'] > last_time_stored
```

You can replace this lambda and take value from your Db or cache etc.

**Trigger right After:**:
Now you can use next operator in combination with this sensor to trigger conditionally.

Note: Here poke_Interval depend on the use case, how often you want to check for modification.

Comment: I will give this a try and get back to you guys! Thanks! Very helpful

Comment: In this case, I dont need to specify schedule_interval in my script right?

Comment: by schudule interval, you mean poke_interval? if you dont want default value, then you will need to. sensor pokes the api after certain interval

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question and out of scope, in order to read the response I need to access the API. So I must grant service account to that particular sheets in order to be able to read the sheet, correct?